# how a vector of objects (with static members) is constructed

Tags: c++, stl, static, vector, constructor

I wrote the following code to test a vector of objects, which have a static member. I expect the output would be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

But the actual output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 6 6 6 6
```

It looks like the static member is not incremented as expected. Can anyone explain this?

```
// ==== test.h =====
using namespace std;

void test();

class Record{
    static int total_number;
    int id;
public: 
    Record();
    void show() {std::cout << id << " "; }
};


// ==== test.cpp ====
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

Record::Record(){
    total_number += 1;
    id = total_number;
 }

void test(){

    const int vec_length = 5;
    Record a[vec_length];

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<vec_length; i++)
        a[i].show();

    cout << endl;    

    vector<Record> vr(vec_length);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<vr.size(); i++)
        vr[i].show();
    cout << endl;
}


// ==== main.cpp =====
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

int Record::total_number = 0;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the definition of `Record::Record()` is where?

Comment: Behold the power of the Copy Constructor...

Answer (score 3):

In C++98/03, your vector is initialized with this constructor:

```
std::vector<Record> v(5, Record());
```

This creates one new object, incrementing the static variable, and then makes five *copies* of this variable to populate the elements. In total, one default- and five copy-constructions, yielding `6 6 6 6 6`

In C++11, the constructor is:

```
std::vector<Record> v(5);
```

This creates space for five elements and value-initializes them, which for your type means that the default constructor is called once for each element. In total, five default-constructions, yielding `6 7 8 9 10`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your definition of `Record::Record` looks like this

```
Record::Record() : id(++total_number) {}
```

and you expect the `vector<Record>` constructor to call just that constructor. However, vector only does that once and copies the rest via the compiler generated copy constructor, which would look something like this:

```
Record::Record(const Record &other) : id(other.id) {}
```

You will have to overwrite that too.

Comment: Reviewing my code I have to ask if my version of default constructor is valid C++.

Comment: @Mooing : Technically, `id` is initialized before the constructor body is even entered, since it was initialized in the constructor's initializer-list.

Comment: @ildjarn: in OPs code, it is uninitialized at the start of the body.  I thought krynr was the OP when I interpreted his comment :(

Comment: @Mooing : Ah I see, sorry for the unnecessary correction. :-]

Answer (score 1):

How a `vector<Record> vr(vec_length);` is somewhat loose. I assume you would be expecting `vec_length` default construction calls, but another viable implementation is to create one default constructed object followed by `vec_length-1` copies. That said, you failed to provide an appropiate copy-constructor.

Comment: This is a somewhat muddled answer for a situation that has entirely standard-specified behaviour... although the answer depends on the language standard!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest (and in the absence of the full code I assume that in Record::Record() you do an ++total_number) that the problem is here

vector vr(vec_length);

which initializes std::vector with vec_length Record's.

std::vector requires its types to be copy-constructible, i.e. you would have to implement Record::Record(const Record&). What happens is this: since std::vector has no Record(), it creates one by constructing it (Record::Record() is called, which increments total count to 6). Then the remaining vec_length-1 records are copied by calling Record::Record(const Record&) with the just created instance.

Since you haven't supplied a copy-ctor, the compiler has created one for you which simply does a bitwise copy of the object. Since vec_length is static to the class, nothing is to be copied - but also since the copy-ctor doesn't increment the static nothing happens (i.e. the value is simply retained).

So the output for these is 6.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the vector constructor you used is as follows:

**explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
Repetitive sequence constructor: Initializes the vector with its content set to a repetition, n times, of copies of value.** Here is the [link to the man page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)

I believe this means that the vector constructor will run your default constructor once (resulting in 6) and then your copy constructor 4 more times (resulting in more 6's).